# How to obtain a test G Suite for Education account

Tags: google-classroom

I've been trying to follow the very sparse [instructions from Google](https://developers.google.com/classroom/access) on how to set up a G Suite for Education domain to test an integration we're developing for Admin and Classroom. We tried applying, but there was no way to flag the application as a developer account for testing, so we were declined. I tried asking G Suite Support for help, but they know nothing about how to get a test account and pointed me here.

I have also tried contacting a [G Suite for Education expert](https://edu.google.com/contact/?modal_active=none), but it's been over a week since they said they'd get back to me "shortly". There doesn't seem to be any other point of contact on the education or developer sites.

Answer (score 0):

From the same link you've provided, notice the "note":

[Get Classroom Test Accounts or Domains](https://developers.google.com/classroom/access)

**Note**: *Standard Gmail accounts can access Classroom, so many use-cases can be tested without requesting any special resources like test accounts or domains.* Please only request a test domain if you are attempting to test some behavior that only applies to G Suite users (for instance, special G Suite administrator functionality).

Comment: As I said, the integration works with both Admin and Classroom, so we need to test parts of the API that only exist in G Suite, e.g. adding users. Standard Gmail accounts do not have access to Admin and cannot manage other accounts on a domain.

Answer (score 0):

We went through the same thing.  The short answer is that you have to know someone on the business side nowadays.  You'll see other links, etc. on stackoverflow, and they sort of get you there, but really, you need your business folks to get a contact.  They have limited bandwidth so will work only with promising companies.

If that's not you or if they can't get those contacts, you'll want to just keep buying domains every 30 days to get your sample account while you build it out.

Comment: Ah... Well this may be the answer I'm looking for, as disappointing as it is. I've been bounced around to so many different departments, all of them ignorant of this process completely, so this must be something quite hidden. This is probably the right answer, but I must note that G Suite for Edu trial licenses only last two weeks, and you don't have have to buy a new domain. We've just used a subdomain (testing.example.tld).

Comment: Good to know!   I believe that link is here for anyone who wants it. The interface is different than when we attempted this a while back, so perhaps things have changed a bit.  https://gsuite.google.com/signup/edu/welcome